# useEffect with function factory gets "React Hook useEffect received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have some side effect logic in multiple components wrapped in `useEffect`, where the logic is exactly the same except taking in different parameters, so I decided to take the logic out and move it into a function factory to supply to `useEffect` so not to repeat the logic everywhere. But once that is done, React is complaining "*React Hook useEffect received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead*". How do you get rid of it the proper way if not suppressing the warning?

e.g.

```
function ComponentA(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
        doThis(props.member);
        doThat(props.member);
    }, [props.member]);
}

function ComponentB(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
        doThis(props.member);
        doThat(props.member);
    }, [props.member]);
}
```

changed to

```
function ComponentA(props) {
    useEffect(logic(props.member), [props.member]);
}

function ComponentB(props) {
    useEffect(logic(props.member), [props.member]);
}

function logic(member) {
    return () => {
        doThis(member);
        doThat(member);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change useEffect to

```
useEffect(() => { 
    logic(props.member);
}, [props.member]);
```

and change logic to

```
function logic(member) {
  doThis(member);
  doThat(member);
}
```